# uploading files directly to server without web service from android

Tags: android, web-services, file, rest, upload

ok so i need to upload files directly to server without using any web service from android ..

first i am doing so with REST web service but the thing is it always say transaction is too large when executing my request .... in android i convert the image into byte[] then into Base64 string from my server side i decode this Base64 string and write bytes into file.

how can i upload directly to folder on my server ... something like executing a function that upload the file to "localhost/myWebApplicationDir/images/"then file here.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this link to be very helpful i discovered that you need an open connection with the server and communicate with streams something like keeping connection alive and upload files bit by bit.... but still you need a web service like @meredrica said.

http://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/android-sending-post-requests-with-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement something that handles uploads as webservers typically don't do that out of the box. I'm sure you can find a POST upload script written in PHP somewhere on google. Then implement some code that POSTs the file to the endpoint and you should be fine.
There are no out-of-the-box tools for this but it's not a lot of work.

Comment: unfortunately i cant use PHP i am using REST with IIS 7 already

Comment: Then you should have a look at the IIS REST documentation. And post some more info. Transaction is too large sounds like a programmers error.